# Github link to my website does not work corectly

Tags: html, github, hyperlink, href

I have linked the website on the github, but when I click on the Gallery button it does not go to the gallery page, it works fine when i open it locally on my pc.
I have updated new repository again and was trying to find the bug but I dont know what is wrong.
Link to the page on my github:
https://maciejrakowski1987.github.io/Smarthome-new-project/

the code looks fine to me:

```
      <div class="col">
    <img src="img/galeriaIcon.png">
    <h2>Galeria</h2>
    <p>Kliknij aby zobaczyć galerie: </p>
    <a class="btn-second" href="gallery.html">dowiedz się więcej</a>
  </div>
```

all the other links work fine.

Comment: It's a typo on gallery, should be Gallery.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html file in github has its first letter uppercase'd. And in the code you have it in lowercase. You should change

```
 <a class="btn-second" href="gallery.html">dowiedz się więcej</a>
```

to

```
 <a class="btn-second" href="Gallery.html">dowiedz się więcej</a>
```

Comment: Please do not farm rep on typo questions, this should be commented.